# How to format a table in LaTeX without vertical separating lines and with caption at the top?

Tags: tables

For the class notes I am working on, I like to keep the Table caption at the top and not at the bottom, and the table output without separating lines. The desired model is enclosed as an image. I worked on table, but result does not match the desired table model.

I enclosed my LaTeX code and desired model as an image.

Your help is highly appreciated! Thanks!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\centering

\begin{tabular}{|c|p{6cm}|c|p{6cm}|}
\hline
& Transfer function approach & & State variable approach \\ \hline 
1. & The transfer function approach is also called the conventional approach or classical approach & 1. 
& The state variable approach is called the modern approach. \\ \hline
2. & It is based on the input-output relationship or transfer function. & 2. &
It is based on the description of a linear system of $n$ first-order differential equations which is
called as a state model.  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Transfer function approach versus the state variable approach}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Desired table model enclosed below..

[image: Table Model]

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "without separating lines". E.g., do you want to get rid of the vertical lines?

Comment: yes,   I like my Table to have a look at this - I will edit my question now.. Kindly check the image.. Thanks

Comment: You can just easily remove some `\hline` commands to disable the horizontal lines. To remove the vertical lines, you need to change your column separators as it is: `\begin{tabular}{cp{6cm}cp{6cm}}`.

Comment: OK thank you - I shall try.. I thought friends may recommend some special package.. Glad I can manage the table with the regular LaTeX formatting commands, thanks

Comment: How to put the caption at the top of the table? When I run LaTeX, the caption comes at the bottom of the table..

Comment: You can just put your caption command just before the `\begin{tabular}` command.

Comment: the caption only comes at the bottom because you placed it there (unless you have a non standard float definition) and the vertical rules are only there as you added them, latex never adds rules by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions, in no particular order:

- If you want the caption to precede rather than follow the tabular material, just place the `\caption` directive *before* rather than after the `tabular` environment.
- If you don't want vertical lines, don't use `|` particles in the argument of the tabular environment.
- To guarantee that the tabular material fits inside the text block, don't use the `p` column type with a fixed width. Instead, load the [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx/) package and use a `tabularx` environment instead of a `tabular` environment and set its desired width to `\textwidth`. (Aside: an `X`-type column is nothing but a `p`-type column for which LaTeX has done the job of calculating the width argument for you.)
- Optional: Suspend full justification in columns 2 and 4 by using `>{\RaggedRight}X` instead of just `X`.
- Optional: For well-spaced horizontal lines, don't use `\hline`. Instead, load the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs/) package and use `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule`, and `\addlinespace`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal lines
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Transfer function approach versus state variable approach}
%% '@{}' particles suppress whitespace padding at both edges
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{2}{ r @{\hspace{6pt}} L } @{}}
\toprule
& \itshape Transfer function approach & & \itshape State variable approach \\ 
\midrule 
1. & The transfer function approach is also called the conventional approach or classical approach & 
1. & The state variable approach is called the modern approach. \\ 
\addlinespace
2. & It is based on the input-output relationship or transfer function. & 
2. & It is based on the description of a linear system of $n$ first-order differential equations which is called as a state model.  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, your LaTeX code and the output are very beautiful! Thanks a lot for a quick reply!! 

Comment: @Dr.Sundar - You're most welcome! Incidentally, while it's of course ok to upvote answers that you feel are good, the site guidelines strongly suggest holding off on "accepting" an answer for several hours, and maybe even a day or two. For by "accepting" an answer early, you effectively discourage other potential answer writers from posting their own, separate answers which may, for all I know, turn out to be even better than mine is.

Comment: OK I removed the upvote for answer as you kindly advised. I was so happy to see your program code and the output it gave. I will wait for 1-2 days, and then upvote the best answer.